# Running xd-shell and admin-ui against a HTTPS xd-admin in springxd 1.0.1 release

Tags: spring-xd

I installed springxd 1.0.1 release. I configured spring-xd to run in HTTPS mode by enabling the SSL properties as specified in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/wiki/Application-Configuration#enabling-https. I am able to start the xd admin and containers successfully after that. I set the httpSSL.properties as well. However, I am not able to get the xd shell properly. or admin UI to run. I know I have to specify these new ssl properties for them to use, but I am not sure where. The output when I run xd shell is:

```
1.0.1.RELEASE | Admin Server Target: http://localhost:9393
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Error: Unable to contact XD Admin Server at 'http://localhost:9393'.
Please execute 'admin config info' for more details.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Welcome to the Spring XD shell. For assistance hit TAB or type "help".
server-unknown:>
```

When I try the admin-ui, I just get a 'Connection Interrupted' error.

EDIT: I tried basic authentication by enabling the properties in servers.yml. With this I am able to get the admin-ui to work, but shell still does not work. I am trying to find which configurations I need to set to make this work unsuccessfully. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

thanks much,

AG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asha,

A few clarifications:

1. You do not need to change httpSSL.properties, that is necessary only for configuring HTTPS for the HTTP source.
2. Since you've enabled https, you must change the target URL accordingly, as follows:

> ```
> xd:> admin config server https://localhost:9393
> ```

(please note that the protocol is https now)

3. If you also enable Basic security, you must add the configuration parameters to the configuration command, as in this example:

> ```
> xd:> admin config server --uri https://localhost:9393 --username adminUserName --password adminPassword
> ```

(As described in the [reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#_configuration_commands))

Hope this helps,
Marius

Comment: Thank you Marius. In addition to the above, I also had to add my host name to the host file

Comment: You're welcome, AGN! Yes, DNS and certificate setup (so that the certificate on the matches the target host) may be required as well (although that's more like infrastructure work). Good point!